# Can my husband from Egypt who I married abroad come to the UK on visitor visa or any other visa besides spouse?

Tags: visas, uk, spouses, egyptian-citizens

My husband’s Egyptian and we got married in Egypt. I am a British citizen currently living in England and I want him to come visit  me but spouse visa is so long to do. I want to know what other visa my husband would be able to come on as we’re already married?

Comment: A spouse visa is for someone intending to live permanently in the UK with their partner. The only route for a *visit* is a Visitor visa.

Comment: If you have the money and meet the conditions, you can pay for the super priority service and probably get a spouse visa faster than a visitor visa. But given the costs involved, make sure you tick all the boxes before you spend that money.

Answer (score 6):

If the plan is that your husband visits you (and then returns to Egypt), a visitor visa is indeed the appropriate one. Him being married to a British citizen is not an issue for his eligibility in principle.

However, his application for a visitor visa would have to somehow overcome the evident motivation for him to overstay, namely the desire to be with his wife. Unless he has a similarly compelling reason to return to Egypt, his chances are probably slim.